# JavaScript: Unicode space character

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, character, innerhtml

I want to insert the space character into the innerHTML of a DOM element, but the space character must be declare in Unicode syntax.

For example, something like this: `...innerHTML += '\u83838383'`;

Answer (score 20):

I am not quite sure what character you are hoping to get with `8383` - not to mention `83838383`, but it certainly doesn't seem to be the space character for any encodings I am familiar with. Are you by chance looking for:

- ASCII Space = `&nbsp;` = `\u0020`
- En Space = `&ensp;` = `\u2002`
- Em Space = `&emsp;` = `\u2003`